# How can i change yui calendar error message?

Tags: yui

I have a problem with YUI 2 calendar. I activated the year selection property of it, and when the user enters a wrong type of year(for example 19m9,aaaa,bbbb), it writes "year needs to be number". How can i change this message, for example "not a valid year or enter a valid year", without changing default js file of calendar? I can change weekday names with

calendar.cfg.setProperty("WEEKDAYS_MEDIUM", ["Son", "Mon", "Die", "Mit", "Don", "Fre", "Sam"]);

but itis not working for changing error message.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The navigator can be configured when creating a Calendar, and the invalidYear message is part of the configuration object:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.Calendar.html#config_navigator

Hope that helps,
Satyen